# Laravel - Return Custom Extra Data in Eloquent Model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have a Advertisement [Eloquent Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) like this-

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Advertisement extends Model
{
    protected $dates        =   ['deleted_at'];

    protected $table        =   'advertisements';           //Table Name

    protected $fillable     =   [
                                    'user_id',
                                    'category_id',
                                    'sub_category_id',
                                    'title',
                                    'price',
                                    'description',
                                    'address',
                                    'location_lat',
                                    'location_lon',
                                    'is_active',
                                    'deleted_at'
                                ];

    protected $hidden = [
                            'user_id',
                            'category_id',
                            'sub_category_id',
                            'deleted_at',
                            'created_at',
                            'updated_at',
                            'is_active',
                        ];

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function UserAdvertisementView()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserAdvertisementView', 'add_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

So it is linked with `UserAdvertisementView` [Eloquent Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent). So, `UserAdvertisementView` is like this-

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserAdvertisementView extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey   =   null;
    public $incrementing    =   false;
    public $timestamps      =   false;

    protected $table        =   'user_add_views';           //Table Name

    protected $fillable     =   [
                                    'user_id',
                                    'add_id',
                                    'total_view'
                                ];
}
```

So, when I am using this in controller-

```
return Advertisement::with('UserAdvertisementView')->get();
```

And getting something like this-

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "as dasd as",
    price: 0,
    description: "asd asdasdasd",
    address: "Khagrachhari, Chittagong Division, Bangladesh",
    location_lat: 23.13,
    location_lon: 91.95,
    user_advertisement_view: [
      {
        user_id: 1,
        add_id: 1,
        total_view: 1
      },
      {
        user_id: 16,
        add_id: 1,
        total_view: 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I like to have something like this-

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "as dasd as",
    price: 0,
    description: "asd asdasdasd",
    address: "Khagrachhari, Chittagong Division, Bangladesh",
    location_lat: 23.13,
    location_lon: 91.95,
    user_advertisement_view: [
      total_view: 3
    ]
  }
]
```

So, I want to have the **SUM** of `total_count` `(2+1 = 3)`  for all users.

So, I need to create a custom query in the [Eloquent Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent).

Is there any way for this?

---

### Update-

According to @Jeff, I have done added this to `Advertisement`-

```
public $appends = ['total_views'];

public function getTotalViewsAttribute()
{
    return $this->UserAdvertisementView->sum('total_view');
}
```

And then made a query like this in controller-

```
return Advertisement::get();
```

And having this-

[image]

So, I am having some extra data which is bad for a better performance when I am working with big data.

So, is there any way to have that extra part removed and just get what we need.

Or is there any way to have custom query in `with` clouse in Eloquent Model?

---

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On your Advertisement model, you can add:

```
public $appends = ['total_views'];

public function getTotalViewsAttribute(){
  return $this->UserAdvertisementView->sum('total_view');
}
```

This will automatically append the `total_views` attribute to your `Advertisement` model when it is sent to JSON.

Comment: Hi @Jeff, thanks for your help, but I am unable to use that.

Can you please add a more detail in your answer so that I need to change where and where? (What change in Model, and what to do the call in controller)

Comment: You just need to add those to your `Advertisement` model.  You do not need to change your controller at all.  The JSON returned by your controller will automatically have an extra line `total_views: 3`

Comment: But have a little problem, I am querying like this- `return Advertisement::get();` and get something like this-

http://joxi.net/4AkogQBIMq7WjA.png but I don't like to have the extra part to save bandwidth and increase performance

Comment: So, is there any way for removing that part?

Comment: And also is there any way to update the use custom get query there?

Comment: @AbrarJahin When you use the `UserAdvertisementView` attribute, it loads the `Collection` of the related objects. You are then calling `sum()` on that `Collection`. If, however, you use the relationship method, it will run a `sum()` query on the database, instead of filling a `Collection` and running sum on that. So: `return $this->UserAdvertisementView()->sum('total_view');` (notice the `UserAdvertisementView()` method, not the `UserAdvertisementView` attribute).

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) It helps me a lot